# Magnolia 6.0 not working on Eclipse+Tomcat (with serve module without publishing)

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, magnolia

I am trying to setup the development environment for Magnolia 6.0 (Eclipse+Tomcat9)
I have an error with enabling "Serve Modules without publishing).
When I disable this option, the project is running properly.

Initializing Log4J
Cannot load config file [WEB-INF/config/default/log4j2.xml], got a IOException :Can't load configuration file: WEB-INF/config/default/log4j2.xml

### 2019-01-03 05:01:20,058 INFO  info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener : Property sources loaded: [DefaultMagnoliaConfigurationProperties with sources: [SystemPropertySource][ServletContextPropertySource from WEB-INF/config/default/magnolia.properties][ModulePropertiesSource from modules [core, dam, freemarker-support, lang-da, lang-el, periscope-api, speech-recognizer, categorization-support, ce-product-descriptor, imaging-support, publishing-core, resource-loader, rest-client, rest-integration, config, i18n, publishing-receiver, publishing-sender, rest-services, cache, content-types, rendering, ui-framework-core, virtual-uri, dam-jcr, ehcache3, imaging, resteasy-client, tasks-app, templating, ui-framework, resources, scheduler, ui-admincentral, ui-framework-jcr, ui-mediaeditor, about-app, cache-app, groovy, log-tools, magnolia-resources-templating, messages-app, pages, password-manager, publishing-app, resources-app, security-app, site, task-management, ui-contentapp, cache-browser-app, contacts, dam-app, dam-imaging, dam-templating, definitions-app, jcr-browser-app, jcr-tools, mail, mte-imaging, periscope-core, site-app, admincentral, form, mte, rest-content-delivery, javascript-models, mtk, rssaggregator, categorization, lang-ar, lang-cs, lang-de, lang-es, lang-fi, lang-fr, lang-he, lang-hr, lang-hu, lang-id, lang-it, lang-ja, lang-ko, lang-nl, lang-no, lang-pl, lang-pt, lang-pt_BR, lang-ru, lang-sk, lang-sq, lang-sv, lang-tr, lang-zh_CN, lang-zh_TW, webapp]][InitPathsPropertySource]]

### MAGNOLIA LICENSE

Version number : 6.0
Core version   : 6.0.0
Build          : 30. November 2018 (rev. 16e89c4505ccdb0a46dd3abd3348c3a5129e361b of UNKNOWN)
Edition        : Community Edition
Provider       : Magnolia International Ltd. (info@magnolia-cms.com)
2019-01-03 05:01:20,205 INFO  info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader       : Initializing content repositories
2019-01-03 05:01:20,205 INFO  info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager : Loading JCR
2019-01-03 05:01:20,221 ERROR info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager : Can't load configuration file: WEB-INF/config/default/repositories.xml
java.io.IOException: Can't load configuration file: WEB-INF/config/default/repositories.xml

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the fix.

Where is your tomcat9 located? , did you check your workspace folder permissions?, 
it's basically hinting that tomcat cant seem to find the files from your eclipse workspace location